# How can i register a module in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a module mydialogBox , I have the .js file included in the .cshtml as a reference.
I have also included it in the

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [ 'mydialogBox']);
```

but i get the following error when i call it.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module mydialogBox due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'mydialogBox ' is not available! You either misspelled the module 
name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

Comment: did you load your module `mydialogBox` by script file before running this script? Can I also see your index.html file?

Comment: ahh yes .. forgot to load , works now